# AngularJS directive does not update on scope variable changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I've tried to write a small directive, to wrap its contents with another template file.

This code:

```
<layout name="Default">My cool content</layout>
```

Should have this output:

```
<div class="layoutDefault">My cool content</div>
```

Because the layout "Default" has this code:

```
<div class="layoutDefault">{{content}}</div>
```

Here the code of the directive:

```
app.directive('layout', function($http, $compile){
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
        var layoutName = (angular.isDefined(attributes.name)) ? attributes.name : 'Default';
        $http.get(scope.constants.pathLayouts + layoutName + '.html')
            .success(function(layout){
                var regexp = /^([\s\S]*?){{content}}([\s\S]*)$/g;
                var result = regexp.exec(layout);

                var templateWithLayout = result[1] + element.html() + result[2];
                element.html($compile(templateWithLayout)(scope));
            });
    }
}
```

});

**My problem:**

When I'm using scope variables in template (in layout template or inside of layout tag), eg. `{{whatever}}` it just work initially. If I update the `whatever` variable, the directive is not updated anymore. The whole link function will just get triggered once.

I think, that AngularJS does not know, that this directive uses scope variables and therefore it will not be updated. But I have no clue how to fix this behavior.

Comment: None of the current answers seem to address the question of why (when using `$compile`) the watch is not automatically set up.  As you say, it is bound in initially...

Comment: I've found another solution, to use template and ng-transclude. This works well - always. The only problem is, that I don't know how to make the layout-template itself configurable. If I use ng-include with a scope function to get the template path, I get a ngTransclude:orphan error.

Comment: Okay, I've found a solution to change templateUrl dynamically. See my own answer below.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You should create a bound scope variable and watch its changes:

```
return {
   restrict: 'E',
   scope: {
     name: '='
   },
   link: function(scope) {
     scope.$watch('name', function() {
        // all the code here...
     });
   }
};
```

Comment: Style tip: The correct variable name should be `scope` and not `$scope`. Inside the `link` function the scope is a plain variable.

Answer (score 42):

I needed a solution for this issue as well and I used the answers in this thread to come up with the following:

```
.directive('tpReport', ['$parse', '$http', '$compile', '$templateCache', function($parse, $http, $compile, $templateCache)
    {
        var getTemplateUrl = function(type)
        {
            var templateUrl = '';

            switch (type)
            {
                case 1: // Table
                    templateUrl = 'modules/tpReport/directives/table-report.tpl.html';
                    break;
                case 0:
                    templateUrl = 'modules/tpReport/directives/default.tpl.html';
                    break;
                default:
                    templateUrl = '';
                    console.log("Type not defined for tpReport");
                    break;
            }

            return templateUrl;
        };

        var linker = function (scope, element, attrs)
        {

            scope.$watch('data', function(){
                var templateUrl = getTemplateUrl(scope.data[0].typeID);
                var data = $templateCache.get(templateUrl);
                element.html(data);
                $compile(element.contents())(scope);

            });



        };

        return {
            controller: 'tpReportCtrl',
            template: '<div>{{data}}</div>',
            // Remove all existing content of the directive.
            transclude: true,
            restrict: "E",
            scope: {
                data: '='
            },
            link: linker
        };
    }])
    ;
```

Include in your html:

```
<tp-report data='data'></tp-report>
```

This directive is used for dynamically loading report templates based on the dataset retrieved from the server.

It sets a watch on the scope.data property and whenever this gets updated (when the users requests a new dataset from the server) it loads the corresponding directive to show the data.

Comment: The $watch() function !! always to resuce. !!

Answer (score 17):

You need to tell Angular that your directive uses a scope variable:

You need to bind some property of the scope to your directive:

```
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      whatever: '='
    },
   ...
}
```

and then `$watch` it:

```
  $scope.$watch('whatever', function(value) {
    // do something with the new value
  });
```

Refer to the [Angular documentation on directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) for more information.

Answer (score 8):

I've found a much better solution:

```
app.directive('layout', function(){
    var settings = {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: function(element, attributes){
            var layoutName = (angular.isDefined(attributes.name)) ? attributes.name : 'Default';
            return constants.pathLayouts + layoutName + '.html';
        }
    }
    return settings;
});
```

The only disadvantage I see currently, is the fact that transcluded templates got their own scope. They get the values from their parents, but instead of change the value in the parent, the value get stored in an own, new child-scope. To avoid this, I am now using `$parent.whatever` instead of `whatever`.

**Example:**

```
<layout name="Default">
    <layout name="AnotherNestedLayout">
        <label>Whatever:</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="$parent.whatever">
    </layout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should keep a watch on your scope.

Here is how you can do it:

```
<layout layoutId="myScope"></layout>
```

Your directive should look like

```
app.directive('layout', function($http, $compile){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            layoutId: "=layoutId"
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
            var layoutName = (angular.isDefined(attributes.name)) ? attributes.name : 'Default';
            $http.get(scope.constants.pathLayouts + layoutName + '.html')
                .success(function(layout){
                    var regexp = /^([\s\S]*?){{content}}([\s\S]*)$/g;
                    var result = regexp.exec(layout);

                    var templateWithLayout = result[1] + element.html() + result[2];
                    element.html($compile(templateWithLayout)(scope));
        });
    }
}

$scope.$watch('myScope',function(){
        //Do Whatever you want
    },true)
```

Similarly you can models in your directive, so if model updates automatically your watch method will update your directive.

Comment: key is to use = on the scope variable and set thrid parameter of $watch as true.  (note @ on the scope variable won't work)

Answer (score 2):

I know this an old subject but in case any finds this like myself:

I used the following code when i needed my directive to update values when the "parent scope" updated. Please by all means correct me if am doing something wrong as i am still learning angular, but this did what i needed;

directive:

```
directive('dateRangePrint', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope:{
        //still using the single dir binding
            From: '@rangeFrom',
            To: '@rangeTo',
            format: '@format'
        },
        controller: function($scope, $element){

            $scope.viewFrom = function(){
                    return formatDate($scope.From, $scope.format);
                }

            $scope.viewTo = function(){
                    return formatDate($scope.To, $scope.format);
                }

            function formatDate(date, format){
                format = format || 'DD-MM-YYYY';

                //do stuff to date...

                return date.format(format);
            }

        },
        replace: true,
        // note the parenthesis after scope var
        template: '<span>{{ viewFrom() }} - {{ viewTo() }}</span>'
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why no one has yet suggested `bindToController` which removes all these ugly `scopes and $watches.` If You are using `Angular 1.4`

Below is a sample DOM:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
        {{ vm.name }}
        <foo-directive name="vm.name"></foo-directive>
        <button ng-click="vm.changeScopeValue()">
        changeScopeValue
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Follows the `controller` code:

```
angular.module('app', []);

// main.js
function MainCtrl() {
    this.name = 'Vinoth Initial';
    this.changeScopeValue = function(){
        this.name = "Vinoth has Changed"
    }
}

angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);

// foo.js
function FooDirCtrl() {
}

function fooDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            name: '='
        },
        controller: 'FooDirCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        template:'<div><input ng-model="name"></div>',
        bindToController: true
    };
}

angular
    .module('app')
    .directive('fooDirective', fooDirective)
    .controller('FooDirCtrl', FooDirCtrl);
```

A Fiddle to play around, here we are changing the scope value in the `controller` and automatically the `directive updates on scope change`.
http://jsfiddle.net/spechackers/1ywL3fnq/

Comment: You aren't even using bindToController in your example.

Answer (score 0):

We can try this

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
    $scope.step1 = true;
    //scope.list2.length = 0;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Etb9d/

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to make the scope variable **object**. Then access the content with `{{ whatever-object.whatever-property }}`. The variable is not updating because JavaScript pass **Primitive** type by **value**. Whereas **Object** are passed by **reference** which solves the problem.