# In Angular, how to force template to recompile when I receive some new data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Suppose I have a directive in which a template contains some data that provide another JS to draw a piechart:

```
mymodule.directive('myGauge', ['$http', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div class="quota-dynamic"><h3>Limit Summary</h3><div class="d3_quota_bar"><div class="pie_chart" data-used="{$ dataUsed $}"></div></div>'

    }
}]);
```

whereas "pie_chart" is used in another JS and it relies data-used value to draw the piechart.

I have another controller which receive the data:

```
mymodule.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.$parent.$watch("toggled", function(toggled) {
        var tenant_id = 1234;
        if (!$scope.$parent.isCollapsed()) {
            $http({
                method: 'get',
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/admin/projects/' + tenant_id + '/test/'
            }).success(function (data, status) {
                $scope.dataUsed = data.totalInstancesUsed / data.maxTotalInstances * 100;
            }).error(function () {
            });
        }
    });
}]);
```

When I receive the data, it is too late for the piechart as it is drawn already. I would like to know if there is a way to force the directive to update the template with new data again?

Thanks.

Comment: Will the data change more than once?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to recompile the template because there are others directive that have to be rerendered, you can add this inside your directive:

```
controller: function($scope,$element){
    $scope.$watch( 'dataUsed', function( newVal, oldVal ){
        $compile($element.contents())($scope);

    });
}
```

This is valid if the scope of the directive is the same as MyCtrl

Answer (score 0):

You will need to keep watch in the controller of your directive.

```
$scope.$watch('dataUsed', function(oldValue, newValue) {
    console.log(oldValue, newValue)
}, true)
```

Comment: But how do I trigger the directive to render the template again?

Comment: if the data is getting changed, automatically it will be updated in your directive template.

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20068526/angularjs-directive-gets-not-updated-if-scope-variable-changes