# How to force recompile of directive with isolated scope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

There are a few SO posts about refreshing a directive when a (model) value changes:

- [Angular Directive refresh on parameter change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856824/angular-directive-refresh-on-parameter-change)
- [AngularJS directive gets not updated if scope variable changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20068526/angularjs-directive-gets-not-updated-if-scope-variable-changes)

The recommended approach is to watch a value on the `scope` **in the linking function**:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch("typeId",function(newValue,oldValue) {
        // This gets called when data changes.
    });
 }
```

Given the following implementation of the **recursive** directive, `<my-directive>`:

```
angular.module('Myapp').directive("MyDirective", function(RecursionHelper) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            data: '=data'
        },
        templateUrl: 'view.html',
        compile: function(tElement, tAttributes) {
            return RecursionHelper.compile(tElement, tAttributes);
        }
    };
});
```

...and the RecursionHelper:

```
angular.module('Myapp').factory('RecursionHelper',
    ['$compile',
    function($compile) {
         var RecursionHelper = {
            compile: function(tElement, tAttrs) {

                var contents = tElement.contents().remove();
                var compiledContents;

                return {
                    post: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
                        if (!compiledContents) {
                            compiledContents = $compile(contents);
                        }

                        compiledContents(scope, function(clone) {
                            iElement.append(clone);
                        });
                    },
                    pre: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) { }
                }
            }
        }
        return RecursionHelper;
    }]);
```

I could add the listener to my linking function:

```
angular.module('Myapp').factory('RecursionHelper',
    ['$compile','MyService',
    function($compile, MyService) {
         var RecursionHelper = {
            compile: function(tElement, tAttrs) {

                var contents = tElement.contents().remove();
                var compiledContents;

                return {
                    post: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
                        if (!compiledContents) {
                            compiledContents = $compile(contents);
                        }

                        compiledContents(scope, function(clone) {
                            iElement.append(clone);
                        });

                        // The listener function.
                        scope.$watch(MyService.data,function(newValue,oldValue) {
                           // This gets called when data changes.
                        });
                    },
                    pre: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) { }
                }
            }
        }
        return RecursionHelper;
    }]);
```

I have added a Service, `MyService`, which contains data that may change and that I'm listening for. The first call to render the directive is started with `main.html`:

```
<my-directive data="data"></my-directive>
```

The directive's compile function is called and ultimately the template, `view.html` is rendered containing the recursive directive:

```
<span ng-repeat="item in data.items">
      <my-directive data="item"></my-directive>
</span>
```

Since the `<my-directive> data` attribute has isolated scope, each nested  directive will have its own 'sandboxed' scope.

Questions

- My `$watch` function never gets called even though `MyService.data` is modified. Is this because the directive has isolated scope?
- Assuming my `$watch` function is called, what is the actual implementation to trigger a recompilation? The SO posts just have comments of console.log statements, but I can't find anything on rendering the entire (root) directive again.

Comment: You would need to do `scope.$watch(function(){ return MyService.data; }, ...)` to make the watch work for this specific stuff. Why are you doing `data="{data}"` did you mean `data="data"`? I did not understand the purpose of recursive helper. Do you have a sample implementation?

Comment: did you got the solution for this. If you get please post the answer

Comment: @rk rk - No, not yet.

Comment: @Jack -  Are you using ui-router ? If not once check whether the scope is changing or not.

Comment: Hey have you made any progress on this? I'm in a similar boat