# ionic back navigation and reload via directive

Tags: angularjs, controller, refresh, ionic-framework, directive

I am trying to build a side menu app.

I have two states: one listing a set of products and the other state that provides detailed product info. You can click on a product from the product list page to be sent to the product details page.

The controllers associated with these states share a directive. The directive provides the current quantity of each product and two buttons to increase or decrease the quantity. The directive will eventually $emit the total cart count back to the controllers when the quantity is changed using buttons.

Here is my problem

1) I am on product list page and change the a product's quantity in the directive scope. 
2) I click on the product and go to the detail page and the changed quantity is reflected just fine
3) I change the quantity on the detail page
3) I use the ionic nav back button to come back the list page
4) The change is prod quantity is not reflected.

How can I ensure that the quantity on the first page is refreshed automatically since it is same directive scope?

**Update**

Did a little research and found my approach was wrong. 
a) My controllers were on different pages and $emit , $broadcast and $watch were not working between the controllers as only one was active at any time

b) While using the ionic nav-back button, the previous page was displayed from history and did not trigger the directive refresh

c) I was able to force the previous page to refresh by setting cache-view="false" on the ion-view tag. I understand this is not an effective way and it will force the page to reload every time

d) The ideal way is to turn off cache and force a reload only if there was a change in the subsequent page. I am planning to use a rootScope variable to track the change in a subsequent page and set the cache-view attribute accordingly. Will post again with results

Comment: if you could share your code that would be great but take a look at this, I am pretty sure you just need to add a $watch to the directive scope and update it when the data changes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20068526/angularjs-directive-does-not-update-on-scope-variable-changes

Comment: The cache-view="false" helped me immensely for dealing with directives and state changes. Thank you!