# update background image via custom directive does not work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

HTML:

```
    <div class="has-bg" back-img="{{currentCoverImg}}" style="min-height: 1000px">
    ......
    </div>
```

I saw [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20068526/angularjs-directive-does-not-update-on-scope-variable-changes) here saying the right way to bind data to a directive and use it in my code. backImg directive looks like:

```
    .directive('backImg', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            bg: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('bg', function () {
                var url = attrs.backImg;
                element.css({
                    'background-image': 'url(../img/' + url + ')'
                });
            })

        }
    }

})
```

it tunes out the background image has only be set for one time when the page initialize. Later on I change the value `currentCoverImg` many times while the background image has never been updated.

**update1**
I choose to use directives rather than ng-style is because I need to do some animation on css change. Such as `element.addClass("ng-hide-remove");`, It looks directive is a feasible way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change attribute to `back-img="currentCoverImg"` without interpolation as you said `=`(two way binding). Also that should be putted inside `bg` attribute as you defined `bg` property in isolated scope.

**Markup**

```
<div class="has-bg" 
  back-img="currentCoverImg" 
  bg="currentCoverImg"
  style="min-height: 1000px">
    ......
</div>
```

And then use `newValue` from `$watch` callback function for current udpated value.

```
scope.$watch('bg', function (url) { //new updated URL value
    element.css({
        'background-image': 'url(../img/' + url + ')'
    });
});
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/7UVUYC9S1x2s2C3dM7SI?p=preview)

---

Though I'd say the better option to achieve the thing would be using `ng-style` directive.

```
<div class="has-bg" 
  ng-style="{ 'background-image': 'url(../img/' + currentCoverImg + ')' }" 
  style="min-height: 1000px">
    ......
</div>
```

Comment: then the absolute url becomes directly suffixed with "currentCoverImg", which is an error. doesn't work :(

Comment: I got url valued as `undefined ` . The ng-style solution will work though. Please check out question updates to see why I prefer to use custom directives.

Comment: On intial go it would be undefined, there after you can see the changes

Comment: the callback of `$watch` was not triggered. I added a `console.log` in the callback while it only shows the very first time. Later when currentCoverImg changes, no messages were printed in the console.

Comment: Have you change attribute to `back-img="currentCoverImg"`?

Comment: yes I did, that was there i saw `undefined`. I guess the problem is why the callback was not triggered.

Comment: No way! it should work, could you please create a plunkr?

Comment: wow it works! So why not simply watch on `backImg` ? This works as well.

Comment: @franky for that you need to tweak isolated scope like `scope: {
            bg: '=bgImg'
        },`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

**change**

```
  scope: {
        bg: '='
    },
```

**to**

```
  scope: {
        bg: '@'
    },
```

```js
var app = angular.module('app',[])
app.controller('ctrl',function($scope){
  
  $scope.currentCoverImg = "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6755dcaf172d19cb9976bedcc56cfed3?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1";
});
app.directive('backImg', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            bg: '@'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('bg', function () {
                var url = attrs.backImg;
                element.css({
                    'background-image': 'url(' + url + ')'
                });
            })

        }
    }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <div class="has-bg" back-img="{{currentCoverImg}}" style="min-height: 1000px">
    ......
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but the sample that created works correctly. please check `url`

Comment: the sample doesn't change url and update. for me the I also initialize well, but no update when I change currentCoverImg